# BackboneJS and jQuery Mobile. Transitions & Show/Hide elements

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I was using http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/ to make BackboneJS work with jQuery mobile. But theres a few  things that might be able to be improved

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```

But this removes the nice default jquery mobile transitions when I navigate from page to page. Basically, I want to use Backbone for page navigation but keep the jquery mobile transitions

---

Another thing is, how can I show hide elements based on what page I am on. What I did currently was in the `render` of my `Backbone.View` call `$(...).show()/.hide()`, definitely not elegant. In jQuery mobile I will need to duplicate the header & footer, and just vary the elements (if I'm not wrong) to get different elements displayed on different views. An example is: I want to show the back and home button on my header bar everytime I am not at home/root of the app ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then modifying JQM to "disable it's routing", so you can use backbone.js's routing you might want to give the [jQuery-mobile-route](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router)r plugin a try, if your app is JQM based anyway it is better probably better suited for your routing since it uses JQM page events. You can still use backbone.js for everything else besides the routing.